# FormTagHelper NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I'm struggling to bug fix this issue with my FormTagHelper where the params I'm attempting to pass through are being interpreted as methods - hence the no method error.

Here's the view:

```
<%= form_tag update_user_email_admin_user_path do %>
 <%= text_field :user, :email, placeholder: 'E-mail or user id' %>
 <%= text_field :user, :new_email, placeholder: 'New e-mail' %>
 <%= submit_tag "Update email", class: 'btn-1 btn-round btn-size-2' %>
<% end %>
```

And here's the controller action (for your reference):

```
def update_user_email
  user_check = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:new_email].downcase.strip)

  if user_check.blank?
    @user.email = params[:user][:new_email].downcase.strip
    @user.save
    flash[:notice] = "Email updated"
  else
    flash[:alert] = "This email is already being used by someone else!"
  end
end
```

And when I load the page in development, this is the no method error:

`NoMethodError at /admin/users/195455`
`undefined method 'new_email' for #<User:0x007f9198c3f560>`

This confuses me because I've used several other FormTagHelpers in the app, with almost identical syntax, and they work fine.

Would love an extra set of eyes on this. I'm a n00b so many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Its assuming you are trying to save value of a `User` in  `new_email`  field, that doesn't exist in your `users` table. Please use `text_field_tag` for this kind of form. you can find the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag) here:

```
<%= form_tag update_user_email_admin_user_path do %>
 <%= text_field_tag 'email', nil , placeholder: 'E-mail or user id' %>
 <%= text_field_tag 'new_email', nil , placeholder: 'New e-mail' %>
 <%= submit_tag "Update email", class: 'btn-1 btn-round btn-size-2' %>
<% end %>
```

Hope it will help.Thanks